# Find items in a table that match a set of conditions in another table

Tags: performance, sql, sql-server

I have two tables. Table 1 has sets of EXPORT conditions: e.g., SET 1 has FOOD, GARMENT, and TECHNOLOGY, and SET 2 contains GARMENT and TECHNOLOGY.

> ```
> TABLE 1
> SETID       EXPORT
> -----------------------
> 1           FOOD
> 1           GARMENT
> 1           TECHNOLOGY
> -----------------------
> 2           GARMENT
> 2           TECHNOLOGY
> -----------------------
> 3           GARMENT
> 3           FOOD
> -----------------------
> 4           TECHNOLOGY
> (more sets of conditions) ...
> ```

Table 2 has a list of countries with different types of exports.

> ```
> TABLE 2
> COUNTRY     EXPORT
> -----------------------
> GERMANY     AUTO
> GERMANY     TECHNOLOGY
> -----------------------
> ITALY       FOOD              
> ITALY       GARMENT 
> -----------------------          
> CHINA       FOOD
> CHINA       GARMENT
> CHINA       TECHNOLOGY
> CHINA       STEEL
> -----------------------
> FRANCE      FOOD
> FRANCE      GARMENT
> -----------------------
> (more countries)...
> ```

I would like to find countries that satisfy each set of the conditions. A country satisfies a set of conditions if it meets all the conditions in a set (even if it may meet additional conditions) -- For example, CHINA satisfies SET 1 even though it also meets the additional condition STEEL.

The expected output is something like:

> ```
> SET          Country
> --------------------------
> 1            CHINA
> 2            CHINA
> 3            ITALY
> 3            CHINA
> 3            FRANCE
> 4            GERMANY
> 4            CHINA
> ...
> ```

Here's the query I have. **It does the job, but I wonder if there is a way to make it perform better.** Currently, when Table 1 has 5000 rows (approx. 600 sets of conditions), and Table 2 has 6 million rows, it takes 15 minutes to get the output.

```sql
WITH TEMP AS (  SELECT   SETID, COUNTRY, COUNT(*) AS TOTALCOUNT
                  FROM   #TABLE1 AS T1
                  JOIN   #TABLE2 AS T2 ON T2.EXPORT = T1.EXPORT
              GROUP BY   SETID, COUNTRY
              )
      SELECT  TEMP.SETID, COUNTRY
        FROM  TEMP
        JOIN  (  SELECT  COUNT(*) AS TOTALCOUNT, SETID
                   FROM  #TABLE1
               GROUP BY  SETID
              ) AS TEMP2 ON  TEMP.TOTALCOUNT = TEMP2.TOTALCOUNT AND TEMP.SETID = TEMP2.SETID
    ORDER BY  TEMP.SETID
```

Code for generating sample tables:

```sql
CREATE TABLE #TABLE1 (SETID INT, EXPORT NVARCHAR(MAX))
INSERT INTO #TABLE1(SETID, EXPORT)
VALUES (1, 'FOOD'), (1, 'GARMENT'), (1, 'TECHNOLOGY'), (2, 'GARMENT'),
       (2, 'TECHNOLOGY'), (3, 'GARMENT'), (3, 'FOOD'), (4, 'TECHNOLOGY');

CREATE TABLE #TABLE2 (COUNTRY NVARCHAR(MAX), EXPORT NVARCHAR(MAX))
INSERT INTO #TABLE2(COUNTRY, EXPORT)
VALUES ('GERMANY', 'AUTO'), ('GERMANY', 'TECHNOLOGY'), ('ITALY', 'FOOD'),              
       ('ITALY', 'GARMENT'), ('CHINA', 'FOOD'), ('CHINA', 'GARMENT'),
       ('CHINA', 'TECHNOLOGY'), ('CHINA', 'STEEL'), ('FRANCE', 'FOOD'),
       ('FRANCE', 'GARMENT');
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the standard logic to find subsets, but 15 minutes for two not really big tables is really a lot.

The join might return a huge result intermediate set (it's a m-n-join), you can check it using:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM   #TABLE1 AS T1
JOIN   #TABLE2 AS T2 ON T2.EXPORT = T1.EXPORT
```

Your query can be simplified a bit using a Group Count before the join:

```
WITH cte AS
 (
   SELECT *, 
      COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY SETID) AS cnt
   FROM #TABLE1
 )
SELECT SETID, COUNTRY
FROM cte
JOIN #TABLE2 AS T2
  ON T2.EXPORT = cte.EXPORT
GROUP BY SETID, COUNTRY
HAVING COUNT(*) = MAX(cte.cnt)
ORDER BY SETID
```

But I don't expect this to improve runtime (unless the optimizer did a very stupid plan before)

### Edit:

As expected, most of the runtime is caused by the huge number (1,500,000,000) of rows in the intermediate result set. For a similar problem (exactly matching two sets) I used a solution based on joining comma-delimited strings of all values in a group (which was very efficient on a Teradata system). This logic can be modified for subsets, but I don't really know about efficiency.

This is the algorithm:

For each country create a comma-delimited list like this:

```
,FOOD,,GARMENT,,STEEL,,TECHNOLOGY,
```

For each set create a comma-delimited list like this:

```
%,GARMENT,%,TECHNOLOGY,%
```

And then simply join using a `LIKE` (the additional commas are needed to prevent matching partial values, e.g. 'TECHNO' matching 'TECHNOLOGY'):

```
WITH cte1 AS
 (
   SELECT SETID, 
      STUFF((SELECT ',%,' + EXPORT 
             FROM  #TABLE1 AS t2
             WHERE t.SETID = t2.SETID 
             ORDER BY EXPORT
             FOR XML PATH('')) + ',%', 1, 1, '') AS x
   FROM #TABLE1 AS t
   GROUP BY setid
 )
,cte2 AS
 (
   SELECT COUNTRY, 
      (SELECT ',' + EXPORT  + ','
       FROM  #TABLE2 AS t2
       WHERE t.COUNTRY = t2.COUNTRY 
       ORDER BY EXPORT
       FOR XML PATH('')) AS x
   FROM #TABLE2 AS t
   GROUP BY COUNTRY
 ) 
SELECT cte1.SETID, cte2.COUNTRY
FROM cte1 JOIN cte2 
ON cte2.x LIKE cte1.x
;
```

Comment: Your query is definitely cleaner than mine. However, I did a few rounds of testing. On average, your query takes about 1 minute longer.

Comment: What's the intermediate row count before aggregation?

Comment: It's HUGE as you said. It's over 1.5 billion rows...

Answer (score 0):

Outside of the SQL query, a couple of places that may help you see improvement is by changing the data types.  If you can, change  the data type for country away from nvarchar(max) to something more reasonable.  A quick google search shows that the longest official country name is [45](http://www.jetpunk.com/user-quizzes/63858/top-20-longest-official-country-names). You could do nvarchar(200) and have a reasonable amount of room to grow.  I'd also recommend changing the data type for export, maybe nvarchar(255) or whatever your longest import name is + a percentage of that number, to allow for growth.

Once you've done this you can play around with [Indexes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188783.aspx), depending on how much of your real life data you're selecting.